# charting libraries for Codeigniter 1.7.2

Tags: codeigniter, libraries

I need a good charting library for my project which is done using Codeiginter. i have searched for libraries found a one called pinaci, but it states that it is for 1.4 and 1.5, can we use it with 1.7.2? can you guys suggest me a good one i can use, which you have used and have past experience?

regards,
Rangana

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your looking for something really simple, I'd recommend using the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) (no library required!) and there's even a [gChart helper](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/gchart/) available if your going to be using charts a lot.

The [CI Charts library](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Category:Library::Charts/) section is pretty small. People have gotten Panaci to [work in CI 1.7](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/131944/#651208). The [Open Flash Chart](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Open_Flash_Chart_2/) is pretty, but it's in flash (kinda lame). And [TeeChart](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/TeeChart_and_CodeIgniter/) is probably overkill.